# Facebook App using Devise is redirecting away from FB Canvas

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth

When the user installs my facebook app for the first time, a facebook logo is displayed, permissions are requested, and then the user is popped out of the iframe.

I applied the directions recently (Oct 14th) added to the [OmniAuth Overview wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) on the devise site regarding [lost sessions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1357).  And this has fixed all my redirect issues except when the permissions dialog shows up.

Anyone else seeing this?  Any idea how to fix?  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own.

The [OmniAuth Overview wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) page suggests the fix below in application_controller.rb to fix lost sessions:

```
def authenticate_user!
  if !current_user
    # This should work, but session is lost. 
    # session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
    redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_apps, :origin => request.fullpath)
  end
end
```

But instead of using **request.fullpath** in the snippet above, the key is to use **request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]** instead.